# Parsing Rest Api Using Kotlin .

Tags: wordpress, rest, kotlin

I am new to kotlin, I am currently trying to get wordpress posts using rest api .

Everything is working however in order for to get the image for each post i needed the "featuredmedia" key data to do that, but the response sent by the api gives a key like "wp:featuredmedia", and i cannot give this as key name in kotlin so how to do it . 
thanks in advance .

Comment: Please show your code, in particular the way you're deserializing JSON responses from the API.

Comment: class Embedded(val wpfeaturedmedia: List<Media>)
class Media(val source_url: String)

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: Please show how you're deserializing the JSON responses from the API. Your comment shows your data class, but it doesn't explain what you use to convert JSON into instances of this data class. There is much more than one way to do that in Kotlin, so no one can give you an answer unless you explain which way you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, sorry for inconvenient response I am new to stackoverflow too :)) .

I finally found how to do it, you just use the @SerializedName tool, already available in kotlin like this:

```
class Embedded(@SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia") val _wpFeaturedmedia: List<MediaDetails>, @SerializedName("wp:term") val _wpTerm: List<List<Term>>) {


val wpFeaturedmedia
get() = _wpFeaturedmedia

val wpTerm
get() = _wpTerm}
```

this is how I did it and it worked in case someone faces the same problem.
thank you again . 
have a nice one .

Comment: You could use `data class` instead